# Why does it stop at -10? sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I was using sympy and when I was making a graph, a line stopped painting at -10

```
p5 = plot((10+x)/2, line_color="cyan")
```

at least in symbolab the same equation continues to infinity
How could I make it continue to infinity?

Comment: Please provide the dataset, and MRE. It's impossible to provide a conclusive answer with the limited information.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't provide enough information to the `plot` function, so it used the default range going from -10 to 10.

However, it's not possible to specify a range from minus infinity to plus infinity. The best thing we can do is to specify a sufficiently large range, for example:

```
p5 = plot((10+x)/2, (x, -1000, 1000), line_color="cyan")
```

Please, read the documentation with `help(plot)` to better understand the available options and see a few more examples.